# Short JQuery code containing the error - what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a script to get the masonry effect. I'm using script I've found on https://masonry.desandro.com/v2/docs/intro.html

```
$(function() {
  $("#new").masonry({
    itemSelector: ".element",
    columnWidth: function(containerWidth) {
      return containerWidth / 2;
    }
  });
});
```

This is a small part of my site but it turns out that the script has some error because the other scripts in my scripts file stop working. If I remove this piece of code everything goes back to normal.

I don't know if it is important but my file (scripts.js) looks something like this:

```
/** Function 1 **/
 $(function() {
 ...

/** Function 2 **/
 $(function() {
 ...

/** Function 3 **/
 $(function() {
 ...
```

I was trying to use some JS validators but it didn't help.

Comment: What does the console say? Rightclick in your browser and chose "inspect", then click on console.

Comment: @infinitezero Sorry but I don't know how to paste code into my comment so it need to look like this:-(

`scripts.js:250 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).masonry is not a function`
`at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scripts.js:250)`

`at fire (jquery-2.2.4.js:3187)`

`at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.2.4.js:3317)`

`at Function.ready (jquery-2.2.4.js:3536)`

`at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-2.2.4.js:3552)`

Comment: I think  you forgot to include `<script src="/path/to/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>` in your code .... you need to include jquery file in order to make use of it. Here, simply copy and paste this path will not work.

Comment: @VeshrajJoshi I have it in my code. It's funny but this piece of code works but other scripts don't. If I'm removing it, everything else start to work.

Comment: I am writing as your console output-once include cdn like - `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.2.1/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>` just below the jquery inclusion... if your code still giving same error then you need to go for some other solution.

Comment: If `masonry` is not a function or not defined, then you most likely either are missing the library/script. Make sure the script loads correctly, maybe an url would be helpfull and full code?

Answer (score -1):

From the look of your sample containerWidth is not defined.

Edit: the comments are correct ignore this, it's wrong

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: And it's also wrong - https://masonry.desandro.com/v2/docs/options.html#columnwidth